# Angular 2+ mongoose, let on array doesn't work due to ID object

Tags: arrays, json, mongoose, let

I am trying to do a let on an array of data that is requested from a mongoose server. 
This works if I don't return the ID object with the rest of the Json data. 
However I want to add the ID data as params to routernavigate to another component.

Is there an easy way of receiving the id as a string rather then an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following to stringify your object data

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(''));//use your result object as parameters
```

as a example `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result['_id']));`